# How can I login into my openshift account via CLI?

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-client-tools

When I type `oc login`, I get:

```
Server [https://localhost:8443]:
```

Now what url should I give to it?

What is openshift server address?

I just pressed enter and I got:

```
error: dial tcp [::1]:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I've also tried rhc but they no longer support that for new users.

Answer (score 1):

What OpenShift instance are you trying to log into?

If you are already logged into the web console, use the drop down menu top right where the question mark is and go to 'Command Line Tools'. That should show you the command to login to that cluster from the command line.

Also suggest you work through the OpenShift interactive learning exercise about how to access an OpenShift cluster. See 'Logging in to an OpenShift Cluster' at:

- https://learn.openshift.com/